# Forced to run assets:precompile two times to get the webpack builds copied to public directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, jsbundling-rails

after long list of issues with rails/webpack there is a last one that hard to understand to fix properly.

I use:

- rails with jsbundling-rails and sprockets-rails
- webpack
- yarn (switched from npm because the command assets:precompile forced me)

When I run the command `assets:precompile` (in fresh cloned code), yarn install is executed, then webpack build it's stuff to `app/assets/builds` (as configured in `webpack.config.js`) and finally jsbundling copy the files into the `public/assets` folder. But... the files builded in `app/assets/builds` are not copied to `public/assets`. I have to run the command a second time and then it's ok. As a workaround, I run the command twice in the CI to build the docker image properly for the production, but it's surprising... the behavior is like if the copy begin **before** webpack emits its compiled files... ‍♂️ (so the second time the copy work because compiled files are here).

First run output:

```
yarn install v1.22.19
[1/4] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
Done in 0.87s.
yarn run v1.22.19
$ webpack
assets by path fonts/ 820 KiB
  assets by path fonts/*.ttf 568 KiB
    asset fonts/fa-solid-900.ttf 385 KiB [emitted] [from: node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-solid-900.ttf] [big] (auxiliary name: application)
    asset fonts/fa-brands-400.ttf 183 KiB [emitted] [from: node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-brands-400.ttf] (auxiliary name: application)
  assets by path fonts/*.woff2 252 KiB
    asset fonts/fa-solid-900.woff2 147 KiB [emitted] [from: node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2] (auxiliary name: application)
    asset fonts/fa-brands-400.woff2 105 KiB [emitted] [from: node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-brands-400.woff2] (auxiliary name: application)
assets by path *.css 312 KiB
  asset application.css 311 KiB [emitted] [minimized] [big] (name: application) 1 related asset
  asset mailer.css 686 bytes [emitted] [minimized] (name: mailer) 1 related asset
  asset document.css 0 bytes [emitted] [minimized] (name: document)
asset application.js 667 KiB [emitted] [minimized] [big] (name: application) 2 related assets
Entrypoint application [big] 978 KiB (3.83 MiB) = application.css 311 KiB application.js 667 KiB 6 auxiliary assets
Entrypoint mailer 686 bytes (88.4 KiB) = mailer.css 1 auxiliary asset
Entrypoint document = document.css
orphan modules 2.55 MiB (javascript) 820 KiB (asset) 2.89 KiB (runtime) [orphan] 247 modules
runtime modules 1.21 KiB 5 modules
cacheable modules 1.52 MiB (javascript) 329 KiB (css/mini-extract)
  modules by path ./node_modules/ 161 KiB 14 modules
  modules by path ./app/assets/ 1.36 MiB (javascript) 329 KiB (css/mini-extract)
    javascript modules 1.36 MiB
      ./app/assets/javascripts/application.js + 150 modules 1.36 MiB [built] [code generated]
      + 3 modules
    css modules 329 KiB
      css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss 328 KiB [built] [code generated]
      + 2 modules

WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets: 
  fonts/fa-solid-900.ttf (385 KiB)
  application.css (311 KiB)
  application.js (667 KiB)

WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
Entrypoints:
  application (978 KiB)
      application.css
      application.js


WARNING in webpack performance recommendations: 
You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/

webpack 5.87.0 compiled with 3 warnings in 38925 ms
Done in 41.06s.
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.445606 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/manifest-b4bf6e57a53c2bdb55b8998cc94cd00883793c1c37c5e5aea3ef6749b4f6d92b.js
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.445936 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/manifest-b4bf6e57a53c2bdb55b8998cc94cd00883793c1c37c5e5aea3ef6749b4f6d92b.js.gz
// removed my application files (images)
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.524605 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/turbo-4851a9a0b1d947e810dfd0448a72aef261d455183ebea681f4f28a73640a9ece.js
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.532303 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/turbo-4851a9a0b1d947e810dfd0448a72aef261d455183ebea681f4f28a73640a9ece.js.gz
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.535589 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/turbo.min-f309baafa3ae5ad6ccee3e7362118b87678d792db8e8ab466c4fa284dd3a4700.js
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.539658 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/turbo.min-f309baafa3ae5ad6ccee3e7362118b87678d792db8e8ab466c4fa284dd3a4700.js.gz
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.546266 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/turbo.min.js-8bc8f4a58d1c106d58dec8bef6c638ff12ff4d078f19d8ebd8c4277f4c9bc85a.map
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.548669 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/turbo.min.js-8bc8f4a58d1c106d58dec8bef6c638ff12ff4d078f19d8ebd8c4277f4c9bc85a.map.gz
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.550194 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/actiontext-28c61f5197c204db043317a8f8826a87ab31495b741f854d307ca36122deefce.js
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.551619 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/actiontext-28c61f5197c204db043317a8f8826a87ab31495b741f854d307ca36122deefce.js.gz
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.552240 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/trix-1563ff9c10f74e143b3ded40a8458497eaf2f87a648a5cbbfebdb7dec3447a5e.js
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.552593 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/trix-1563ff9c10f74e143b3ded40a8458497eaf2f87a648a5cbbfebdb7dec3447a5e.js.gz
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.553620 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/trix-ac629f94e04ee467ab73298a3496a4dfa33ca26a132f624dd5475381bc27bdc8.css
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.555522 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/trix-ac629f94e04ee467ab73298a3496a4dfa33ca26a132f624dd5475381bc27bdc8.css.gz
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.558989 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/es-module-shims-69d0cb4dc1d01c9dc2ed52f2ab66874fd545fe7e35c7841009b4e8c55f231dee.js
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.560070 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/es-module-shims-69d0cb4dc1d01c9dc2ed52f2ab66874fd545fe7e35c7841009b4e8c55f231dee.js.gz
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.561524 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/es-module-shims.min-4ca9b3dd5e434131e3bb4b0c1d7dff3bfd4035672a5086deec6f73979a49be73.js
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.565186 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/es-module-shims.min-4ca9b3dd5e434131e3bb4b0c1d7dff3bfd4035672a5086deec6f73979a49be73.js.gz
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.567158 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/es-module-shims.js-c69f1a5dd068dfc08a4cedc0ad77b792985bf256e162852bd03cdf764b666c4a.map
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.568719 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/es-module-shims.js-c69f1a5dd068dfc08a4cedc0ad77b792985bf256e162852bd03cdf764b666c4a.map.gz
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.571255 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/stimulus-1bd52683afde5c8ff5572f5d49429cea5bf7744ca636fcb830c015d8cccf353e.js
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.571877 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/stimulus-1bd52683afde5c8ff5572f5d49429cea5bf7744ca636fcb830c015d8cccf353e.js.gz
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.574041 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/stimulus-autoloader-c584942b568ba74879da31c7c3d51366737bacaf6fbae659383c0a5653685693.js
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.575693 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/stimulus-autoloader-c584942b568ba74879da31c7c3d51366737bacaf6fbae659383c0a5653685693.js.gz
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.578330 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/stimulus-importmap-autoloader-db2076c783bf2dbee1226e2add52fef290b5d31b5bcd1edd999ac8a6dd31c44a.js
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.579039 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/stimulus-importmap-autoloader-db2076c783bf2dbee1226e2add52fef290b5d31b5bcd1edd999ac8a6dd31c44a.js.gz
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.581233 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/stimulus-loading-1fc59770fb1654500044afd3f5f6d7d00800e5be36746d55b94a2963a7a228aa.js
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.587586 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/stimulus-loading-1fc59770fb1654500044afd3f5f6d7d00800e5be36746d55b94a2963a7a228aa.js.gz
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.590919 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/stimulus.min-d03cf1dff41d6c5698ec2c5d6a501615a7a33754dbeef8d1edd31c928d17c652.js
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.591492 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/stimulus.min-d03cf1dff41d6c5698ec2c5d6a501615a7a33754dbeef8d1edd31c928d17c652.js.gz
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.592633 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/stimulus-autoloader-c584942b568ba74879da31c7c3d51366737bacaf6fbae659383c0a5653685693.js
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.593696 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/stimulus-autoloader-c584942b568ba74879da31c7c3d51366737bacaf6fbae659383c0a5653685693.js.gz
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.595387 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/stimulus-importmap-autoloader-db2076c783bf2dbee1226e2add52fef290b5d31b5bcd1edd999ac8a6dd31c44a.js
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.595881 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/stimulus-importmap-autoloader-db2076c783bf2dbee1226e2add52fef290b5d31b5bcd1edd999ac8a6dd31c44a.js.gz
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.596629 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/stimulus-loading-1fc59770fb1654500044afd3f5f6d7d00800e5be36746d55b94a2963a7a228aa.js
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.597384 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/stimulus-loading-1fc59770fb1654500044afd3f5f6d7d00800e5be36746d55b94a2963a7a228aa.js.gz
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.599151 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/stimulus.min.js-0f3bbd3e2e72e4d7178153a52d180de4086e47082ecfc388ce82a90d8a3d7480.map
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.601141 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/stimulus.min.js-0f3bbd3e2e72e4d7178153a52d180de4086e47082ecfc388ce82a90d8a3d7480.map.gz
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.602650 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/activestorage-3ab61e47dd4ee2d79db525ade1dca2ede0ea2b7371fe587e408ee37b7ade265d.js
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.604317 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/activestorage-3ab61e47dd4ee2d79db525ade1dca2ede0ea2b7371fe587e408ee37b7ade265d.js.gz
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.604719 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/activestorage.esm-01f58a45d77495cdfbdfcc872902a430426c4391634ec9c3da5f69fbf8418492.js
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.604945 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/activestorage.esm-01f58a45d77495cdfbdfcc872902a430426c4391634ec9c3da5f69fbf8418492.js.gz
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.605207 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/actioncable-5433453f9b6619a9de91aaab2d7fc7ff183e5260c0107cbc9a1aa0c838d9a74e.js
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.605576 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/actioncable-5433453f9b6619a9de91aaab2d7fc7ff183e5260c0107cbc9a1aa0c838d9a74e.js.gz
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.605778 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/actioncable.esm-e01089c3ec4fe7817fa9abcad06cab6bdc387f95f0ca6aab4bf7ba7537f70690.js
I, [2023-07-07T17:41:37.605948 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/actioncable.esm-e01089c3ec4fe7817fa9abcad06cab6bdc387f95f0ca6aab4bf7ba7537f70690.js.gz
```

Second execution:

```
yarn install v1.22.19
[1/4] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
Done in 0.88s.
yarn run v1.22.19
$ webpack
assets by path fonts/ 820 KiB
  assets by path fonts/*.ttf 568 KiB
    asset fonts/fa-solid-900.ttf 385 KiB [compared for emit] [from: node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-solid-900.ttf] [big] (auxiliary name: application)
    asset fonts/fa-brands-400.ttf 183 KiB [compared for emit] [from: node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-brands-400.ttf] (auxiliary name: application)
  assets by path fonts/*.woff2 252 KiB
    asset fonts/fa-solid-900.woff2 147 KiB [compared for emit] [from: node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2] (auxiliary name: application)
    asset fonts/fa-brands-400.woff2 105 KiB [compared for emit] [from: node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-brands-400.woff2] (auxiliary name: application)
assets by path *.css 312 KiB
  asset application.css 311 KiB [compared for emit] [minimized] [big] (name: application) 1 related asset
  asset mailer.css 686 bytes [compared for emit] [minimized] (name: mailer) 1 related asset
  asset document.css 0 bytes [compared for emit] [minimized] (name: document)
asset application.js 667 KiB [compared for emit] [minimized] [big] (name: application) 2 related assets
Entrypoint application [big] 978 KiB (3.83 MiB) = application.css 311 KiB application.js 667 KiB 6 auxiliary assets
Entrypoint mailer 686 bytes (88.4 KiB) = mailer.css 1 auxiliary asset
Entrypoint document = document.css
orphan modules 2.55 MiB (javascript) 820 KiB (asset) 2.89 KiB (runtime) [orphan] 247 modules
runtime modules 1.21 KiB 5 modules
cacheable modules 1.52 MiB (javascript) 329 KiB (css/mini-extract)
  modules by path ./node_modules/ 161 KiB 14 modules
  modules by path ./app/assets/ 1.36 MiB (javascript) 329 KiB (css/mini-extract)
    javascript modules 1.36 MiB
      ./app/assets/javascripts/application.js + 150 modules 1.36 MiB [built] [code generated]
      + 3 modules
    css modules 329 KiB
      css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss 328 KiB [built] [code generated]
      + 2 modules

WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets: 
  fonts/fa-solid-900.ttf (385 KiB)
  application.css (311 KiB)
  application.js (667 KiB)

WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
Entrypoints:
  application (978 KiB)
      application.css
      application.js


WARNING in webpack performance recommendations: 
You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/

webpack 5.87.0 compiled with 3 warnings in 37803 ms
Done in 39.75s.
I, [2023-07-07T17:43:02.412265 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/application-35848cd1492d48b4309b0f94b61041b45367b3c88b40a8ec446a42fbbccf7c4f.css
I, [2023-07-07T17:43:02.412984 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/application-35848cd1492d48b4309b0f94b61041b45367b3c88b40a8ec446a42fbbccf7c4f.css.gz
I, [2023-07-07T17:43:02.413873 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/fonts/fa-solid-900-c15a3b77a1df1d41545fcaa78bca78411ba2c1dd2f1a08f61be156bf463a4925.woff2
I, [2023-07-07T17:43:02.417531 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/fonts/fa-solid-900-8254be23b50ccdd44fb95da3be612dba6548398b35ae990c87342ef0f5c0b926.ttf
I, [2023-07-07T17:43:02.420742 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/fonts/fa-solid-900-8254be23b50ccdd44fb95da3be612dba6548398b35ae990c87342ef0f5c0b926.ttf.gz
I, [2023-07-07T17:43:02.422070 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/fonts/fa-brands-400-71069435092e2b6c23cd74d2dcbb1b2f2f12e0da5f79f9a978d19c863c7b2846.woff2
I, [2023-07-07T17:43:02.424849 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/fonts/fa-brands-400-57a98fe5c49399cacfe08ae0c15a27d848717559c82e0a44351babebdb5f80cb.ttf
I, [2023-07-07T17:43:02.440974 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/fonts/fa-brands-400-57a98fe5c49399cacfe08ae0c15a27d848717559c82e0a44351babebdb5f80cb.ttf.gz
I, [2023-07-07T17:43:02.441724 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/application.css-bd63fb6e806f1ff28b45920fc9882316ee8942b5daf58594699390516dbdd916.map
I, [2023-07-07T17:43:02.450383 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/application-463b75aa95834378675b3403de79acc32ff1dac12f1c06fdd5ffbaa155bd6699.js
I, [2023-07-07T17:43:02.451465 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/application-463b75aa95834378675b3403de79acc32ff1dac12f1c06fdd5ffbaa155bd6699.js.gz
I, [2023-07-07T17:43:02.452618 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/application.js.LICENSE-745370248ae8913cc0f319511d41079cc6c4d77aad4511b01a52f6f5f91d694f.txt
I, [2023-07-07T17:43:02.453503 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/application.js.LICENSE-745370248ae8913cc0f319511d41079cc6c4d77aad4511b01a52f6f5f91d694f.txt.gz
I, [2023-07-07T17:43:02.454835 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/application.js-3257015c5b8246a2e8c266bc1c8268473bd14a1bade6e148eb2af1a6c2266814.map
I, [2023-07-07T17:43:02.460830 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/application.js-3257015c5b8246a2e8c266bc1c8268473bd14a1bade6e148eb2af1a6c2266814.map.gz
I, [2023-07-07T17:43:02.462258 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/document-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css
I, [2023-07-07T17:43:02.463038 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/document-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css.gz
I, [2023-07-07T17:43:02.468231 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/fonts/fa-brands-400-57a98fe5c49399cacfe08ae0c15a27d848717559c82e0a44351babebdb5f80cb.ttf.gz
I, [2023-07-07T17:43:02.471371 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/fonts/fa-solid-900-8254be23b50ccdd44fb95da3be612dba6548398b35ae990c87342ef0f5c0b926.ttf.gz
I, [2023-07-07T17:43:02.473643 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/mailer-5deacbeb1b407e6ac5869de2622fb67f51f8b0b684d9655b193c56c87296d0cc.css
I, [2023-07-07T17:43:02.474215 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/mailer-5deacbeb1b407e6ac5869de2622fb67f51f8b0b684d9655b193c56c87296d0cc.css.gz
I, [2023-07-07T17:43:02.474680 #1]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/public/assets/mailer.css-3dc564609f4e2f4be522dae30714218bed24584100f6b66e718541f35fa320bb.map
```

As you can see, webpack make the same in the first and second execution. But emitted files are copied only on the second execution (application.css application.js)... 
Thank you in advance, I can provide more configurations if needed.

Comment: I was thinking it could be a bug with the lib, and found this: https://github.com/rails/jsbundling-rails/issues/162

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self answering: webpack, on build, removes the `app/assets/builds` folder (because of the `clean` directive in `webpack.config.js`) that then causing the issue with `assets:precompile`. I've added a `.keep` file in it and added an exception for the clean config:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  output: {
    // ...
    clean: {
      keep: ".keep",
    }
  }
}
```